# Should threadMessage in the SimpleThreads example be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety

Should the `threadMessage` method  in the [`SimpleThreads` example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) be `synchronized` in principle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean [this code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html):

```
// Display a message, preceded by
// the name of the current thread
static void threadMessage(String message) {
    String threadName =
        Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                      threadName,
                      message);
}
```

my answer is no, there's no shared state to protect, so no further locking is required (over what's already being done in the things being called).

Getting the currentThread already does whatever locking it needs (if any). The format method writes the formatted string to stdout, where the PrintStream does locking to make sure the messages written don't get jumbled together and each line gets written separately.

Storing the thread name in the local variable threadName means it has its own storage on its own stackframe (allocated for that particular method call), the local variable contents can't get overwritten by any other call to this method (by another thread or by the same thread either). If threadName was a static variable then you would need to synchronize so that it wouldn't get overwritten between the call to the currentThread method and the format method. Making the variable local keeps things simple.

If multiple threads call this method at the same time there are no opportunities for anything to happen except the entries can show up in a different order in stdout. Which can happen anyway.